# stsadm migrateuser error "Your changes could not be saved because this SharePoint Web site has exceeded the storage quota limit"

Tags: stsadm, migrate

In SharePoint 2007 when I run the following command:

```
stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin "OLDDOMAIN\username" -newlogin"NEWDOMAIN\username" -ignoresidhistory
```

I get the following error:

> Your changes could not be saved because this SharePoint Web site has exceeded the storage quota limit.

I am doing a migration of one user across multiple SharePoint sites in the Farm.  It doesn't say in the error which website is causing the quota limit issue so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it is becuase one of the site collection having quota problem where this user having some kind of permission.

you can check the ULS logs or run the below script to find the quota of all site collections in your web app, from there you will know which site collections having quota problem.

Copy the code in notepad and save the file with a .PS1 extension, for example ScriptName.PS1. The script can be run on any server in the SharePoint farm from within a Windows PowerShell window using .\ScriptName.PS1.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
#Configure the location for the output file
$Output="C:\Output.csv";
"Site URL"+","+"Owner Login"+","+"Owner Email"+","+"Root Site Last Modified"+","+"Quota Limit (MB)"+","+"Total Storage Used (MB)"+","+"Site Quota Percentage Used" | Out-File -Encoding Default -FilePath $Output;
#Specify the root site collection within the Web app
$Siteurl="http://intranet.contoso.com";
$Rootweb=New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Spsite($Siteurl);
$Webapp=$Rootweb.Webapplication;
#Loops through each site collection within the Web app, if the owner has an e-mail address this is written to the output file
Foreach ($Site in $Webapp.Sites)
{if ($Site.Quota.Storagemaximumlevel -gt 0) {[int]$MaxStorage=$Site.Quota.StorageMaximumLevel /1MB} else {$MaxStorage="0"}; 
if ($Site.Usage.Storage -gt 0) {[int]$StorageUsed=$Site.Usage.Storage /1MB};
if ($Storageused-gt 0 -and $Maxstorage-gt 0){[int]$SiteQuotaUsed=$Storageused/$Maxstorage* 100} else {$SiteQuotaUsed="0"}; 
$Web=$Site.Rootweb; $Site.Url + "," + $Site.Owner.Name + "," + $Site.Owner.Email + "," +$Web.LastItemModifiedDate.ToShortDateString() + "," +$MaxStorage+","+$StorageUsed + "," + $SiteQuotaUsed | Out-File -Encoding Default -Append -FilePath $Output;$Site.Dispose()};
```

[Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2013/07/25/windows-powershell-script-to-output-site-collection-information.aspx)